# How to capture current dynamic output of JSP and email it?

Tags: email, jsp, struts2

In my webapplication, a JSP page outputs to the webpage, the list of users logged in that day. I want to mail the same output to specifics mail-ids. What all Struts2 tags do I need to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grab the HTML using JavaScript and send it as request parameter.

```
<div id="content">
    ... (here you should put content which you'd like to mail)
</div>

<form action="mail" method="post" onsubmit="html.value = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('content').innerHTML)">
    <input type="hidden" name="html" />
    <input type="submit" value="Mail this document" />
</form>
```

It'll be available as request parameter with name `"html"` in Struts2/Servlet side. The emailing job can be done with help of [JavaMail](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html).