# Get HTML content by HttpServletResponse / HttpServletRequest

Tags: spring, jsp, servlets, spring-mvc

Is there any way to obtain a HTML content by HttpServletResponse or HttpServletRequest?

I need to print a PDF based on HTML object.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Capture generated dynamic content at server side](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1963158/capture-generated-dynamic-content-at-server-side) and [How to capture current dynamic output of JSP and email it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7400408/how-to-capture-current-dynamic-output-of-jsp-and-email-it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this scenerio i would use a filter. 
You can access content which wanted to be output and redirect the output stream to your PDF generator which can convert HTML to PDF.

More about Filters : 
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html

common way is to create PDFs from model objects. 
Then use iText. 
http://itextpdf.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can create a PDF from the HTTP request data and whatever other information you need from the server side by merging it into a Velocity template containing the FO defining your PDF.